# Django audiofield

Tags: django, audio

I am using audiofield in my Django application to allow upload of a .wav file and render it for play.

I am able to succesfully implement it for one upload at a time, showing the player for a single uploaded file

The code is :

```
 def bottom_player(self):
            if self.a_file:
                    file_url = settings.MEDIA_URL + str(self.a_file)
                    Html5_string = '<div style="position:fixed; top:5em; right:5em; height: 5em; background-color:white;"><audio controls><source src="%s" type="audio/mpeg">%s Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio><br><h3>Audio player will adjust to your screen</h3></div>' % (file_url, os.path.basename(self.a_file.name))
                    return Html5_string
 bottom_player.allow_tags = True
```

Now, I want to show separate player for multiple uploaded files, so I have created another table having a_file field for upload and a SQL trigger to copy the newly created a_file field value to the previous a_file column in comma separated format

audio-file-NACHY-1698934831.wav, ./audio-file-ABGYT-1890930931.wav

To parse this a_file column values and then show player for each path, the code looks like:

```
def bottom_player(self):
            if self.a_file:
                    audiolist = self.a_file
                    filenamelist = audiolist.split(",")
                    filenamelist
                    for filename in filenamelist:
                            file_url = settings.MEDIA_URL + str(filename)
                            Html5_string += '<div style="position:fixed; top:5em; right:5em; height: 5em; background-color:white;"><audio controls><source src="%s" type="audio/mpeg">%s Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio><br><h3>Audio player will adjust to your screen</h3></div>' % (file_url, os.path.basename(self.filename))
                    return Html5_string
  bottom_player.allow_tags = True
```

I get "None" in my bottom player field in the Django page.